# Backup - Windows, Linux, Encrypted, Network

Tags: linux, windows, backup

I currently have 2 computers, one with Windows 8 and another with a dual-boot Ubuntu/Windows 7.

I also have a Synology NAS in a remote location.

I want to be able to backup my data in a homogeneous way accross my computers and OSs to the NAS.

I would also like to be able to encrypt the backup during the transfer and to have the choice of whether to do it or not on the NAS.

So far I haven't found what I was looking for...

Any input would be much appreciated !

So far:

- Baccula: install process on the synology is complicated and I'd rather not modify my NAS
- Rsync: only on Linux? Plus no encryption?
- SyncBackUp: Windows only and no encryption
- Cobian: Windows only

Comment: I would simply encrypt the NAS then any tool you used would automatically encrypt the backup archives.  There are dozens of software solutions to duplicate the data on your hdd.  Your requirements are to vague so I won't provide specific examples even though product suggestions are not on topic.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this site was quite free on the topic... Is there a more adapted site ? Yeah but this is not an option : Synology doesn't allow this. I could probably install truecrypt and mount the locker but the installation will be a pain and I don't really want to modify my NAS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crashplan is hands down the best solution I have come across.  It allows you to backup any number of computers for free even to a synology (mapped as a network drive).  If you want off site backup you can pay for Crashplan Central but it sounds like thats not exactly what you want.

Crashplan works on Windows, Mac, Linux, encrypts the data, keeps incremental backups, and even does deduplication and compression.  I use it extensively at work and at home and I've found it to be more effective than any of the solutions you mentioned above.

Just a disclaimer, I don't work for Crashplan, i'm just a very satisfied customer.

[Crashplan Website](http://Crashplan.com)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll dig into that. I only knew it for the cloud offer and did not know they offer an application of this kind!

Comment: Just to clarify, it's the same application, once you download you can choose if you want to backup locally, to a friends computer, or to the cloud (paid).